# CodeIgniter custom error messages not working?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've read the documentation but this form is still displaying the default messages?

As I understand i'm setting a rule and then applying a message to that rule?

> https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> ', '</p>'); //Controls what element the error is put in, <p> by default.//
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('Username', 'username required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Password', 'Password', 'trim|required|callback_CheckDatabase');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('Password', 'password required');
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you need to set a custom error message for a particular field on
>   some particular rule, use the set_rules() method:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('field_name', 'Field Label', 'rule1|rule2|rule3',
    array('rule2' => 'Error Message on rule2 for this field_name')
);
```

You are using old docs. [Documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#setting-error-messages).